# Postgresql: inner join takes 70 seconds

Tags: database, performance, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have two tables -

Table A : 1MM rows, 
AsOfDate, Id, BId (foreign key to table B)

Table B : 50k rows,
Id, Flag, ValidFrom, ValidTo

Table A contains multiple records per day between 2011/01/01 and 2011/12/31 across 100 BId's.
Table B contains multiple non overlapping (between validfrom and validto) records for 100 Bids.

The task of the join will be to return the flag that was active for the BId on the given AsOfDate.

```
select 
    a.AsOfDate, b.Flag 
from 
    A a inner Join B b on 
        a.BId = b.BId and b.ValidFrom <= a.AsOfDate and b.ValidTo >= a.AsOfDate
where
    a.AsOfDate >= 20110101 and a.AsOfDate <= 20111231
```

This query takes ~70 seconds on a very high end server (+3Ghz) with 64Gb of memory.

I have indexes on every combination of field as I'm testing this - to no avail.

Indexes : a.AsOfDate, a.AsOfDate+a.bId, a.bid
Indexes : b.bid, b.bid+b.validfrom

Also tried the range queries suggested below (62seconds)

This same query on the free version of Sql Server running in a VM takes ~1 second to complete.

any ideas?

Postgres 9.2

Query Plan

```
QUERY PLAN                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate  (cost=8274298.83..8274298.84 rows=1 width=0)
->  Hash Join  (cost=1692.25..8137039.36 rows=54903787 width=0)
    Hash Cond: (a.bid = b.bid)
     Join Filter: ((b.validfrom <= a.asofdate) AND (b.validto >= a.asofdate))
     ->  Seq Scan on "A" a  (cost=0.00..37727.00 rows=986467 width=12)
           Filter: ((asofdate > 20110101) AND (asofdate < 20111231))
     ->  Hash  (cost=821.00..821.00 rows=50100 width=12)
           ->  Seq Scan on "B" b  (cost=0.00..821.00 rows=50100 width=12)
```

see http://explain.depesz.com/s/1c5 for the analyze output

[image: here is the query plan from sqlserver for the same query]

Comment: Please post `explain (buffers, analyze)`, Pg version, etc as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Are there any indices on your tables?

Comment: yes - i've tried lots of combinations - i've updated the text to include the latest iterations

Comment: The date (asofdate) filter interval is a whole year. As that is probably a big part of table A then the planner will have no option other than sequential scan that table. What happens if you lower that interval to a day or week? You could try to cluster the table on that column's index.

Comment: @Clodoaldo - agreed on the table scan of A - but the join to B should be by id with index, and i can't for the life of me see how this should take as long as it does.

Comment: what are your autovacuum settings? also, when was the last time vacuum was run?

Comment: You didn't mention an index on a.BId other than where it is second to a.AsOfDate

Comment: @Clodoaldo updated the body - i did have it just forgot to include

Comment: @swasheck - autovaccum is off, but i ran it with no change.  note these are test tables that have only been populated once.

Comment: Have you tried index on `b.ValidTo` field? If table A contains only records from 2011., why do you even have `WHERE` part of your query? Have you tried reversing order of tables A and B in INNER JOIN?

Comment: @MiljenMikic the where is there as in my prod tables i'll have many years of data in that table  - also indexing validfrom has no effect

Comment: @headsling Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding your situation or otherwise being dense, but it looks to me like the problem here is that, because BId is not unique in either table, once the hash join on a.BId = b.BId is done poor Postgres is left with a joined table of 54903787 (half a billion) rows on which to evaluate the condition ((b.validfrom <= a.asofdate) AND (b.validto >= a.asofdate)) one by one. This is possibly a silly approach by Postgres, but I honestly don't know how it *should* be handling your query. Perhaps you should post a query plan from SQL Server to see how it handles it?

Comment: @headsling A workaround for your problem if you are to continue using Postgres: since the rows in table B are non-overlapping, could you give table B a unique key column (say, b.unique_id) if it doesn't already have one, and then create a column in table A that references b.unique_id, and that stores the unique_id of the row in table b that satisfies your join condition here (that is, a.BId = b.BId and b.ValidFrom <= a.AsOfDate and b.ValidTo >= a.AsOfDate). You would need to populate the column from your existing data, and tweak any INSERT or UPDATE queries you use to keep it up to date, but

Comment: @headsling (continued)... it would hopefully let you do near-instant joins in future. Anyhow, I am keen to see a query plan from SQL Server and see what black magic it is using to be able to handle this query in ~1 second.

Comment: @MarkAmery thanks for the comments - i've uploaded the query plan. 1/2 billion isn't that many in the scheme of things and given the entire table fits in memory i can't see that many ops taking that long ..

Comment: @MarkAmery - i could definatly add a lookup key, but imagine the cost of updating my B table to insert a new record in the past ... unlimited number of updates to re-point A to the new records!

Comment: Any question that asks about debugging query performance must include actual table definitions for us to give a meaningful answer that is more than guessing.  Describing table layouts without showing the actual layouts is like describing source code without showing the actual source code.

Comment: @headsling Afraid my limited SQL knowledge isn't enough to offer any further insights upon seeing that SQL Server plan. Hopefully someone else can offer some help.

Comment: i have to be missing an index somewhere - i'll keep plugging

Comment: @headsling, please, post `explain analyze` output for your query.

Comment: This might be more suitable over on our DBA Q&A site: http://dba.stackexchange.com/ - flag or @ ping me if you want it migrated over (do not cross post). Thanks.

Comment: A compound index on `B(bid, validTo asc, validFrom desc)` can be used to satisfy the join condition with an index range scan. Try that index; if postgres doesn't use it, try again `set random_page_cost=1` to reflect your knowledge that B is entirely cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues was with the indexes - for some reason unclear to me, the indexes on the tables were not being referenced correctly by the query analyzer - i removed them all, added them back (exactly the same - via script) and the query now takes ~303ms.

thanks for all the help on this very frustrating problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the range types available in postgresql 9.2:

```
create index on a using gist(int4range(asofdate, asofdate, '[]'));
create index on b using gist(int4range(validfrom, validto, '[]'));
```

You can query for a date in a matching a range like so:

```
select * from a
where int4range(asofdate,asofdate,'[]') && int4range(20110101, 20111231, '[]');
```

And for rows in b overlapping a record in a like so:

```
select *
from b
    join a on int4range(b.validfrom,b.validto,'[]') @> a.asofdate
where a.id = 1
```

(`&&` means "overlaps", `@>`means "contains", and `'[]'` indicates to create a range that includes both end points)

Comment: seems like the range is slower (explain confirms the use of the range index) - 
select count(1) from a where int4range( 20110101, 20110505, '[]' ) && int4range( asofdate,asofdate, '[]' );               
Time: 179.939 ms

select count(1) from a where asofdate >= 20110101 and asofdate <= 20110505;
Time: 149.114 ms